# How to make Android Studio make automatic pull from git on start?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, startup

Is it possible to configure android studio to make automatic pull from git (github.com or gitlab.com) on startup? 
P.S. I understand that it's not always good idea but in 99% cases I need that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: I don't think there is a way to configure it, but you can do it at wish, there is a menu called VCS on your android studio, under it, you will see a sub menu called git, from there you will see pull

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Add a gradle task gitPull to your app build.grade file that looks like:

```
task gitPull(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'git', 'pull'
}
```

Navigate through android studio menus:  File -> Settings -> Tools -> StartupTasks

Here you can add gradle tasks to run on startup. Add the gitPull task you just created using the green plus sign on the right.

After you reopen android studio, it will build / sync / index like normal, then a build screen will pop up from the bottom running git pull and showing you the command line output. This will happen automatically every time you open android studio.

Good luck, hope it works for you as well as it does for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linux, you could do this from bash script before calling android-studio.

Create a bash script with:

```
cd [project-folder]
git pull user@password:project-address
call android-studio
```